# How to get the latest version of Java to install

Tags: java

I've been having an issue with the latest versions of Java, they won't install, and there's no information from Sun about when they're going to fix this bug.

So:
1) Why does java update fail to install with the latest updates? (6.32) (7.5)
The installer gets to 99% done, then it bails with an error message, and at that point, java has been uninstalled on the machine, requiring me to reinstall java 6.31.

And if it's not possible to fix this bug or get around it, what about:
2) How can I version stamp my systems so they don't try to install the update, at least until I can verify the bug has been fixed.

Comment: Count / OS / Failed / Succeeded  - 12 W2K / 12 / 0  - 4 / XP / 3 / 1  - 2 / W2008 / 2 / 0  - 2 / W7 / 2 / 0  Hopefully this formats according to the boards weird syntax of not permitting the use of enter to format a table, ... Nope.

Comment: WARNING: Java 6.32 is not the latest version, and has not been for a long time.  The latest version is (currently) Java 7.0 update 51.  The last publicly released version of Java was Java 6.0 update 45 ... and you should NOT be installing Java 6 in peoples' web browsers because it is no longer getting security updates.  Java 6 has been "end-of-lifed".

Comment: In short, anyone trying to use this Question to solve their problems would be better off ignoring it entirely ...

Answer (score 0):

Do you want JDK Version ? If you cannot install, maybe something is wrong with your machine than error in JDK package. But, if you want to have newest version. Here is another way : (and again, this works nice, if your OS doesn't have some problem).

I assume you are using windows. Install JDK in another machine, and copy all of this folder to your Computer. For example, `C:\JDK 1.7\`

**Change your environment variable :**

Going to `Environment Variable` Dialog (it is different on Windows Xp and Windows 7 )

At `Path`, add `C:\JDK 1.7\bin`

At `system variable`, you add new variable named : `JAVA_HOME` and set value for it is : `C:\JDK 1.7`
 Note that no `bin` after this path.

Hope this help :)

Comment: I think we're talking banana's and pears, I'm referring to the Java that runs in the browser when you visit a website with an applet, not looking to code anything in Java.